# Use Android share intent in Javascript in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent

I would like to bring up the Android Share menu from Javascript in Chrome for Android.
I know that you can launch a specific app from Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

Is there a way to use href="intent://..." to open the Share menu?
This is how it is done in an app: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: here is solution https://sdtuts.com/javascript-android-native-share-popup-navigator-share-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is you can't.

I made this sample: http://jsbin.com/AdAPEmu/2 which constructs the Intent as it would appear for Android and Chrome doesn't recognise it, it needs a package to go with it.

Answer (score 4):

There is `navigator.share` as an [experimental technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) mentioned in MDN.

Also described more in [Google Developers page.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share)

From chrome 61 you can do this, here is [demo I found online](https://wicg.github.io/web-share/demos/share.html). I've tested it on latest Android Chrome (on Android Oreo) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This article, [Triggering a native Share intent on Android from the web](https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/), may provide more details about why triggering intents from a web page doesn't currently work as well as it could.

So, yes, apparently you can make this work, but probably only with your own target applications (applications for which you have control over the manifest).