# How can I pass a url to an android app using href?

Tags: android, html, uri, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm trying to pass a link to mpv-android. I want to do it via href using intents
Something like this :
`<a href="mpv//https://video/url.mp4">`
But its not working. Can someone help me with this.

mpv-android github:https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android/issues/366). Since the manifest filters depending on MIME type or URLs with a few select extensions (mkv, mp4, webm, m3u, ...) you need to trick Android into opening mpv anyway by specifying a valid-looking type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an intent

Check these out.

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284726/use-android-share-intent-in-javascript-in-chrome)
- [2](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)
- [3](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-url-scheme-in-android/)
- [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102542/how-to-launch-an-android-app-with-custom-url-scheme)

Comment: I'm just confused with the format. Here the android:scheme is equal to "https" . Then what will be format of <a href></a>

Comment: yeah but i need to pass the url to the app using intents. So I'm confused in the syntax.

Comment: @Maverick2000 have a look at this page example link http://output.jsbin.com/AdAPEmu/2

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen tried the syntax from the example. But it directly goes to the playstore for some reason `<a href="intent://https://youtu.be/bM7SZ5SBzyY/#Intent;scheme=https;package=is.xyz.mpv;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end">`